# How can I use decimal in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, safemath, math

how can i calculate:
1083.83 / 8.25 = 131.37.

As I see its not possible in simple way. I have tried a lot of math function but not works.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Maintain each one of them as a pair of numerator and denominator. If the same denominator is used everywhere (for example, 100 in your case), then you only need to maintain the numerators (for example, 108383, 825 and 13137 in your case). When you apply arithmetic operations, always try to "postpone" the operation `/` (or `div` if you're using some sort of `SafeMath` library) as far as possible towards the end of the computation, in order to minimize precision-loss.

Comment: For example, instead of `xN / xD + yN / yD`, you can do `(xN * yD + yN * xD) / (xD * yD)`.

Comment: And instead of `xN.div(xD).add(yN.div(yD))`, you can do `xN.mul(yD).add(yN.mul(xD)).div(xD.mul(yD))`.

Comment: Does it answer your question? Or do you have a specific scenario in which you need a different solution? If yes, then please add it to your question.

Comment: This answer resolved my issue but i can't found button "Resolved".

Comment: You can't, because it's a comment, not an answer. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maintain every non-integer entity in your code as a pair of numerator and denominator.

If the same denominator is used everywhere (for example, 100 in your case), then you can maintain only the numerators (for example, 108383, 825 and 13137 in your case).

Whenever you apply an arithmetic computation, try to "postpone" the operation `/` (or `div` if you're using some sort of `SafeMath` library) as far as possible towards the end of the computation, in order to minimize precision-loss.

For example, instead of:

```
uint256 a = xN  /  xD   +  yN  /  yD  ;
uint256 b = xN.div(xD).add(yN.div(yD));
```

You can do:

```
uint256 a = (xN  *  yD   +  yN  *  xD )  / (xD  *  yD );
uint256 b =  xN.mul(yD).add(yN.mul(xD)).div(xD.mul(yD));
```